# How do I validate multiple models with Yii?

Tags: php, validation, yii

I am using the following code to save and validate Booking and BookingRoom(link table) models, but I can only validate one at a time. I have had success in that the following saves and populates my database, but the validation occurs in sequence.

$Booking->save();

$BookingRoom->save();

How do I validate and save multiple models?

Comment: You can always validate like `if($model->validate() && $BookingRoom->validate()) { $model->save(false); $BookingRoom->save(false); }` `SOME_MODEL->save()` will always need to be called separately.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm not getting any error messages.

Comment: You mean no error messages even if the form has errors?

Comment: Error messages are displayed for the Booking model, but not for the BookingRoom model.

Comment: The answer given by @Everton will do the trick. I mean the way `$valid` is used.

Comment: Can you please add the new code in the question?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I don't know what the code is doing though... could you explain $valid=$a->validate();
    $valid=$b->validate() && $valid;

Comment: Explanation is added as a separate answer. I hope its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the validate() method from the model, like the example bellow:

```
// populate input data to $a and $b
    $a->attributes=$_POST['A'];
    $b->attributes=$_POST['B'];

    // validate BOTH $a and $b
    $valid=$a->validate();
    $valid=$b->validate() && $valid;

    if($valid)
    {
        // use false parameter to disable validation
        $a->save(false);
        $b->save(false);
        // ...redirect to another page
    }
```

See this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/) for more information.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I don't know what the code is doing though... could you explain $valid=$a->validate(); $valid=$b->validate() && $valid;

Comment: @Kunal explained at the answer bellow :)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of `$valid=$a->validate(); $valid=$b->validate() && $valid;` -

1. `$valid=$a->validate();` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` according to the validation.

   So lets say `$valid=TRUE`.
2. Now when `$valid=$b->validate() && $valid;` is executed,

   the next model's validate is performed and some value is returned `(TRUE OR FALSE)`.
3. Statements will look like either `$valid = TRUE && TRUE;` or `$valid = FALSE && TRUE;`

So now the value of `$valid` in `if($valid) { [...] }`, is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

and code will be executed accordingly.